Keyboard encoding during boot via KVM

OpenBSD 7.6 fresh install
Choosing "no" as keyboard encoding during install - working
Keyboard connected via KVM
Reboot -> login prompt
At login prompt; when pressing any key, the system recognizes the USB keyboard
Able to login, but with different/standard keyboard encoding (UK/US)

After login, keyboard encoding successfully changed using wsconsclt and I've updated /etc/wsconsctl.conf accordingly (keyboard.encoding=no), however, when I reboot, the keyboard encoding settings seems to be lost.
Any way to make the keyboard encodings stick, regardless of which keyboards are connected when, during boot?
Running on a Dell PowerEdge R210 II.
dmesg:
OpenBSD 7.6 (GENERIC.MP) #338: Mon Sep 30 08:55:35 MDT 2024
    deraadt@amd64.openbsd.org:/usr/src/sys/arch/amd64/compile/GENERIC.MP
real mem = 8539275264 (8143MB)
avail mem = 8257208320 (7874MB)
random: good seed from bootblocks
mpath0 at root
scsibus0 at mpath0: 256 targets
mainbus0 at root
bios0 at mainbus0: SMBIOS rev. 2.7 @ 0xe66c0 (57 entries)
bios0: vendor Dell Inc. version "2.10.0" date 05/24/2018
bios0: Dell Inc. PowerEdge R210 II
acpi0 at bios0: ACPI 4.0
acpi0: sleep states S0 S4 S5
acpi0: tables DSDT FACP SPMI ASF! HPET APIC MCFG BOOT SSDT ASPT SSDT SPCR HEST ERST BERT EINJ
acpi0: wakeup devices P0P1(S4) GLAN(S0) EHC1(S4) EHC2(S4) XHC_(S4) RP01(S5) PXSX(S4) RP02(S5) PXSX(S4) RP03(S5) PXSX(S4) RP04(S5) PXSX(S4) RP05(S5) PXSX(S4) RP06(S5) [...]
acpitimer0 at acpi0: 3579545 Hz, 24 bits
acpihpet0 at acpi0: 14318179 Hz
acpimadt0 at acpi0 addr 0xfee00000: PC-AT compat
cpu0 at mainbus0: apid 0 (boot processor)
cpu0: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31220 @ 3.10GHz, 1596.40 MHz, 06-2a-07, patch 0000002f
cpu0: cpuid 1 edx=bfebfbff<FPU,VME,DE,PSE,TSC,MSR,PAE,MCE,CX8,APIC,SEP,MTRR,PGE,MCA,CMOV,PAT,PSE36,CFLUSH,DS,ACPI,MMX,FXSR,SSE,SSE2,SS,HTT,TM,PBE> ecx=17bae3ff<SSE3,PCLMUL,DTES64,MWAIT,DS-CPL,VMX,SMX,EST,TM2,SSSE3,CX16,xTPR,PDCM,PCID,SSE4.1,SSE4.2,x2APIC,POPCNT,DEADLINE,AES,XSAVE,AVX>
cpu0: cpuid 6 eax=75<SENSOR,ARAT> ecx=9<EFFFREQ>
cpu0: cpuid 7.0 edx=9c000400<MD_CLEAR,IBRS,IBPB,STIBP,L1DF,SSBD>
cpu0: cpuid a vers=3, gp=8, gpwidth=48, ff=3, ffwidth=48
cpu0: cpuid d.1 eax=1<XSAVEOPT>
cpu0: cpuid 80000001 edx=28100800<NXE,RDTSCP,LONG> ecx=1<LAHF>
cpu0: cpuid 80000007 edx=100<ITSC>
cpu0: MELTDOWN
cpu0: 32KB 64b/line 8-way D-cache, 32KB 64b/line 8-way I-cache, 256KB 64b/line 8-way L2 cache, 8MB 64b/line 16-way L3 cache
cpu0: smt 0, core 0, package 0
mtrr: Pentium Pro MTRR support, 10 var ranges, 88 fixed ranges
cpu0: apic clock running at 99MHz
cpu0: mwait min=64, max=64, C-substates=0.2.1.1, IBE
cpu1 at mainbus0: apid 2 (application processor)
cpu1: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31220 @ 3.10GHz, 1596.42 MHz, 06-2a-07, patch 0000002f
cpu1: smt 0, core 1, package 0
cpu2 at mainbus0: apid 4 (application processor)
cpu2: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31220 @ 3.10GHz, 1596.41 MHz, 06-2a-07, patch 0000002f
cpu2: smt 0, core 2, package 0
cpu3 at mainbus0: apid 6 (application processor)
cpu3: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E31220 @ 3.10GHz, 1596.42 MHz, 06-2a-07, patch 0000002f
cpu3: smt 0, core 3, package 0
ioapic0 at mainbus0: apid 0 pa 0xfec00000, version 20, 24 pins
acpimcfg0 at acpi0
acpimcfg0: addr 0xe0000000, bus 0-255
acpiprt0 at acpi0: bus 0 (PCI0)
acpiprt1 at acpi0: bus 2 (P0P1)
acpiprt2 at acpi0: bus 1 (RP01)
acpiprt3 at acpi0: bus -1 (RP02)
acpiprt4 at acpi0: bus -1 (RP03)
acpiprt5 at acpi0: bus -1 (RP04)
acpiprt6 at acpi0: bus -1 (RP05)
acpiprt7 at acpi0: bus -1 (RP06)
acpiprt8 at acpi0: bus -1 (RP07)
acpiprt9 at acpi0: bus -1 (RP08)
acpiprt10 at acpi0: bus -1 (PEG0)
acpiprt11 at acpi0: bus -1 (PEG1)
acpiprt12 at acpi0: bus -1 (PEG2)
acpiprt13 at acpi0: bus -1 (PEG3)
acpipci0 at acpi0 PCI0: 0x00000010 0x00000011 0x00000000
"IPI0001" at acpi0 not configured
acpicmos0 at acpi0
"PNP0A05" at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0A05" at acpi0 not configured
com0 at acpi0 UAR3 addr 0x3f8/0x8 irq 4: ns16550a, 16 byte fifo
com1 at acpi0 UAR4 addr 0x2f8/0x8 irq 3: ns16550a, 16 byte fifo
"PNP0C14" at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0C0B" at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0C0B" at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0C0B" at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0C0B" at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0C0B" at acpi0 not configured
acpicpu0 at acpi0: C3(350@104 mwait.1@0x20), C2(500@80 mwait.1@0x10), C1(1000@1 mwait.1)
acpicpu1 at acpi0: C3(350@104 mwait.1@0x20), C2(500@80 mwait.1@0x10), C1(1000@1 mwait.1)
acpicpu2 at acpi0: C3(350@104 mwait.1@0x20), C2(500@80 mwait.1@0x10), C1(1000@1 mwait.1)
acpicpu3 at acpi0: C3(350@104 mwait.1@0x20), C2(500@80 mwait.1@0x10), C1(1000@1 mwait.1)
acpipwrres0 at acpi0: FN00, resource for FAN0
acpipwrres1 at acpi0: FN01, resource for FAN1
acpipwrres2 at acpi0: FN02, resource for FAN2
acpipwrres3 at acpi0: FN03, resource for FAN3
acpipwrres4 at acpi0: FN04, resource for FAN4
acpitz0 at acpi0: critical temperature is 95 degC
ipmi at mainbus0 not configured
cpu0: using VERW MDS workaround (except on vmm entry)
pci0 at mainbus0 bus 0
pchb0 at pci0 dev 0 function 0 "Intel Xeon E3-1200 Host" rev 0x09
ehci0 at pci0 dev 26 function 0 "Intel 6 Series USB" rev 0x04: apic 0 int 20
usb0 at ehci0: USB revision 2.0
uhub0 at usb0 configuration 1 interface 0 "Intel EHCI root hub" rev 2.00/1.00 addr 1
ppb0 at pci0 dev 28 function 0 "Intel 6 Series PCIE" rev 0xb4: msi
pci1 at ppb0 bus 1
bnx0 at pci1 dev 0 function 0 "Broadcom BCM5716" rev 0x20: apic 0 int 16
bnx1 at pci1 dev 0 function 1 "Broadcom BCM5716" rev 0x20: apic 0 int 17
ehci1 at pci0 dev 29 function 0 "Intel 6 Series USB" rev 0x04: apic 0 int 23
usb1 at ehci1: USB revision 2.0
uhub1 at usb1 configuration 1 interface 0 "Intel EHCI root hub" rev 2.00/1.00 addr 1
ppb1 at pci0 dev 30 function 0 "Intel 82801BA Hub-to-PCI" rev 0xa4
pci2 at ppb1 bus 2
vga1 at pci2 dev 3 function 0 "Matrox MGA G200eW" rev 0x0a
wsdisplay0 at vga1 mux 1: console (80x25, vt100 emulation)
wsdisplay0: screen 1-5 added (80x25, vt100 emulation)
pcib0 at pci0 dev 31 function 0 "Intel C202 LPC" rev 0x04
ahci0 at pci0 dev 31 function 2 "Intel 6 Series AHCI" rev 0x04: msi, AHCI 1.3
ahci0: port 0: 3.0Gb/s
ahci0: port 1: 3.0Gb/s
ahci0: port 4: 1.5Gb/s
scsibus1 at ahci0: 32 targets
sd0 at scsibus1 targ 0 lun 0: <ATA, Hitachi HUA72302, MK7O> naa.5000cca223e4d90f
sd0: 1907729MB, 512 bytes/sector, 3907029168 sectors
sd1 at scsibus1 targ 1 lun 0: <ATA, Hitachi HUA72302, MK7O> naa.5000cca223e4e7a9
sd1: 1907729MB, 512 bytes/sector, 3907029168 sectors
cd0 at scsibus1 targ 4 lun 0: <TSSTcorp, DVD+-RW TS-L633J, D250> removable
ichiic0 at pci0 dev 31 function 3 "Intel 6 Series SMBus" rev 0x04: apic 0 int 19
iic0 at ichiic0
sdtemp0 at iic0 addr 0x19: mcp98243
sdtemp1 at iic0 addr 0x1b: mcp98243
spdmem0 at iic0 addr 0x51: 4GB DDR3 SDRAM ECC PC3-12800 with thermal sensor
spdmem1 at iic0 addr 0x53: 4GB DDR3 SDRAM ECC PC3-12800 with thermal sensor
isa0 at pcib0
isadma0 at isa0
pckbc0 at isa0 port 0x60/5 irq 1 irq 12
pcppi0 at isa0 port 0x61
spkr0 at pcppi0
uhub2 at uhub0 port 1 configuration 1 interface 0 "Intel Rate Matching Hub" rev 2.00/0.00 addr 2
uhub3 at uhub1 port 1 configuration 1 interface 0 "Intel Rate Matching Hub" rev 2.00/0.00 addr 2
uhub4 at uhub3 port 2 configuration 1 interface 0 "QinHeng Electronics WCH.CN" rev 2.00/9.00 addr 3
uhub4: port 2 reset failed
uhub5 at uhub3 port 5 configuration 1 interface 0 "Standard Microsystems product 0x2514" rev 2.00/0.00 addr 4
vscsi0 at root
scsibus2 at vscsi0: 256 targets
softraid0 at root
scsibus3 at softraid0: 256 targets
sd2 at scsibus3 targ 1 lun 0: <OPENBSD, SR RAID 1, 006>
sd2: 1907728MB, 512 bytes/sector, 3907028576 sectors
root on sd2a (6824914e7e7bf790.a) swap on sd2b dump on sd2b
bnx0: address d0:67:e5:f1:a3:f3
brgphy0 at bnx0 phy 1: BCM5709, rev. 8
bnx1: address d0:67:e5:f1:a3:f4
brgphy1 at bnx1 phy 1: BCM5709, rev. 8
uhidev0 at uhub4 port 1 configuration 1 interface 0 "PixArt HP USB Optical Mouse" rev 2.00/1.00 addr 5
uhidev0: iclass 3/1
ums0 at uhidev0: 3 buttons, Z dir
wsmouse0 at ums0 mux 0
uhidev1 at uhub4 port 2 configuration 1 interface 0 "PixArt HP USB Optical Mouse" rev 2.00/1.00 addr 6
uhidev1: iclass 3/1
ums1 at uhidev1: 3 buttons, Z dir
wsmouse1 at ums1 mux 0
wsmouse0 detached
ums0 detached
uhidev0 detached
uhidev0 at uhub4 port 1 configuration 1 interface 0 "CHICONY HP Basic USB Keyboard" rev 2.00/1.30 addr 5
uhidev0: iclass 3/1
ukbd0 at uhidev0: 8 variable keys, 6 key codes
wskbd0 at ukbd0: console keyboard, using wsdisplay0
umass0 at uhub5 port 2 configuration 1 interface 0 "General UDisk" rev 2.00/1.00 addr 7
umass0: using SCSI over Bulk-Only
scsibus4 at umass0: 2 targets, initiator 0
sd3 at scsibus4 targ 1 lun 0: <General, UDisk, 5.00> removable
sd3: 1900MB, 512 bytes/sector, 3891200 sectors
sd3 detached
scsibus4 detached
umass0 detached
umass0 at uhub5 port 1 configuration 1 interface 0 "General UDisk" rev 2.00/1.00 addr 7
umass0: using SCSI over Bulk-Only
scsibus4 at umass0: 2 targets, initiator 0
sd3 at scsibus4 targ 1 lun 0: <General, UDisk, 5.00> removable
sd3: 1900MB, 512 bytes/sector, 3891200 sectors
sd3 detached
scsibus4 detached
umass0 detached
umass0 at uhub5 port 2 configuration 1 interface 0 "General UDisk" rev 2.00/1.00 addr 7
umass0: using SCSI over Bulk-Only
scsibus4 at umass0: 2 targets, initiator 0
sd3 at scsibus4 targ 1 lun 0: <General, UDisk, 5.00> removable
sd3: 1900MB, 512 bytes/sector, 3891200 sectors


The sd3 mumbo at the bottom is just part of my dmesg transfer.

Are you concerned about the keyboard layout in the console or in X11? Did you say you're running the OpenBSD system within KVM?

Keyboard encoding is handled by kbd, so you'd run kbd <encoding> to change the encoding.
The default can be stored in /etc/kbdtype (a single line with "no", in your case).  When existing, the contents of this file is fed as an argument to kbd by the /etc/rc script (around line 440, if you're curious) upon startup.
The man page for kbd has all the details.

/etc/kbtype containing "no" already existed as well, and it turns out it's the KVM switch causing the USB keyboard to remain invisible until a key is pressed at login prompt. Thus the rc script is unable to set the encoding during boot. I managed to work  around the problem by setting keyboard encoding in a hotplugd attach script.

Thanks for the update on the workaround. Your workaround shouldn't be needed, otherwise we'd have to to that everytime a USB keyboard is plugged in. I think the underlying cause is: you have a pckbc device (a ISA keyboard driver) but no pckbd device attaches to it (and hence no wskbd), and thus the encoding isn't set. Maybe a "legacy keyboard"-like BIOS setting will emulate a pckbd device.
